# How to prevent user from going back to previous page in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I have tried this, but the back page is showing for 1 or 2 secs and after that it comes back to the current page. I don't want to go to Backpage even for 1 or 2 sec.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function preventBack() { window.history.forward(); }
    setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
    window.onunload = function () { null };
</script>
```

I have write this code in Asp.net .aspx file.

Is their any other way?

Answer (score 1):

What you are wanting to do is client side logic. So asp.net vs node vs php doesn't really enter into this.

You are on the correct track. I'd suggest adding a window.history.pushState({}, '', window.location) to your initial code so the browser sees the first back button press as hitting the same page. Also check out window.onhashchange

Answer (score 0):

I think this snippet will help you out:

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);
    window.onpopstate = function () {
        window.history.go(1);
    };
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation as to how/why this code fixes the issue.